# spark streaming delta table cache

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, rdd, delta-lake

spark 3.2.1
delta 1.2.1
scala 2.12.12
hadoop 3.3.0

I am reading stream from delta table in gen1, processing data and writing stream to gen2.
Most of the batches take short time measured in < 1 minute but every other batch ~every 30min takes roughly ~14minutes.

I noticed in SparkUI in Storage tab 2 x RDD:

```
Delta Table State #116243 - wasbs://INPUT_PATH/_delta_log  Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated 3.4 GiB (Size in Memory)
Delta Table State #60042 - abfss://OUTPUT_PATH/_delta_log Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated 55.7 GiB (Size in Memory)
```

Are these cache RDDs and their sizes a problem?